# common.h: no such file or directory : Ubuntu

Tags: opengl, ubuntu, graphics

I am trying to compile a program(in OpenGL) in `Ubuntu`, but I am receiving this error

```
fatal error: common.h: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure on which package I need to install for this.

Comment: Where is the `#include <common.h>`?

Answer (score 6):

`common.h` is not part of any package. I suspect you took the code out of some project or a tutorial that was part of a whole set of programs. And `common.h` is a header common to all those projects.

Answer (score 5):

If you arrive at this page, it's possibly because your going through the 'Introduction to Operating Systems' book and tried to copy the code from the intro chapter directly and compile. At least, that's why I ended up here. This won't work, and will throw the above error.

It's best to [download the code directly](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) from the source and compile what they give you. Enjoy!

Comment: Link to "intro chapter" mentioned above is here: https://github.com/remzi-arpacidusseau/ostep-code/tree/master/intro